# How can I asynchronously update multiple objects in the same array in React?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I have an application with a class as defined below:

```
class Point {
  id: string;
  position: Coordinate;
  elevation?: number;
}
```

In my application I store an array of points.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState<Point[]>([]);
```

In the code below, I have a useEffect hook that depends on the `points` array; any time `points` changes, the effect scans for points with `undefined` elevation and queries *asynchronously* for the elevation. When individual queries return, a callback `handleUpdatePoint` is called to update that particular Point with a new elevation value.

```
  // Any time the Points array changes, checks each Point for undefined elevation
  // and queries for it
  //  ISSUE: If more than one elevation query has yet to resolve, there will be an unintended
  //         state if one query resolves while one or more queries are pending
  useEffect(() => {
    points.forEach((p) => {
      if (p.elevation === undefined) {
        ElevationQuery(p.position.lat, p.position.lng, (elevation) => {
          handleUpdatePoint(p.id, { elevation: elevation });
        });
      }
    });
  }, [handleUpdateSteerpoint, points]);`
```

**The issue I'm facing is that if multiple queries are pending at the same time, the state of `points` is overwritten as multiple results return, thus losing elevation results for some of my queries. How can I fix this?**

---

**EDIT #1: `handleUpdatePoint` added for reference**

```
const handleUpdatePoint = useCallback(
    (id: string, newPointData: Partial<Point>) => {
      // shallow copy the points array
      const pointsClone = [...points];

      // the point we are updating
      const targetPoint = getPointById(id);

      // preserve all other points as they are, but update the target point
      // with the new data
      const updatedPoints: Point[] = pointsClone.map((p: Point) => {
        if (p.id !== id) {
          return p;
        } else {
          // if the target point has a position, change its elevation to undefined
          if (newPointData.position) {
            newPointData.elevation = undefined;
          }

          const updatedPoint: Point = update(targetPoint, { $merge: newPointData })!;
          return updatedPoint;
        }
      });

      setPoints(updatedPoints);
    },
    [getPointById, points]
  );
```

Comment: I think Using Promise.all would help in this case.

Comment: can you provide your handleUpdatePoint function?

Comment: @e.a. Added as Edit #1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just using a callback-style of updating your state would solve the issue:

```
setPoints((previousPoints) =>
  previousPoints.map((p: Point) => {
    if (p.id !== id) {
      return p;
    } else {
      // if the target point has a position, change its elevation to undefined
      if (newPointData.position) {
        newPointData.elevation = undefined;
      }

      const updatedPoint: Point = update(targetPoint, {
        $merge: newPointData,
      })!;
      return updatedPoint;
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Of course! I can't believe I missed that. That way, no matter what order the queries return in, `points` will always reference the last value of `points` and then append the updated point to that array, right?

Comment: yes. and you don't need the cloning part. the setState callback already gives you that. just create your updated point & append your new point to that previous points array that you can access in useState callback

Comment: I think I need to clone since I need to keep the order of my points the same.

Comment: ok, gotchu. updated the answer to satisfy that requirement. you still don't need to clone though

Comment: How about a race condition from multiple instances of that useEffect running?